# $(Y|X=x)\sim Poiss(x),(X)\sim Geo(p).P(Y=0)=?$

Tags: probability

Consider $(Y|X=x)\sim Poiss(x),(X)\sim Geo(p)$
$$P(Y=0)?$$
(The final answer is $\frac{p}{e-\left(1-p\right)}$, but my question is how they got it)
So far i wrote this:
$$P(Y=0)  = \sum_{x}^{ }P(X=x)\cdot P(Y=0|X=x) = \sum_{x}^{ }p(1-p)^{x-1}\cdot P(Y=0|X=x)$$
But from here i don't know to put instead of $P(Y=0|X=x)$. I know that $(Y|X=x)\sim Poiss(x)$ but only i know is that when $Z\sim poiss(\lambda ) $ then $P(Z=k) = \frac{e^{-\lambda }\cdot \lambda ^{k}}{k!}$
What i'm missing?

Comment: $P(Y=0\mid X=x)=\frac{e^{-x}.x^0}{0!}=e^{-x}$

Comment: @drhab why you can do this?

Comment: Based on the data the $(Y\mid X=x)$ is Poisson-$x$ distributed. You find $P(Z=0)=e^{-\lambda}$ right? Here the same with $x$ taking the place of $\lambda$.

Comment: @drhab yes, but we don't want to calculate P(Z=0) here. we want calculate P(Y=0).

Comment: Which is done exactly the same way, but now with parameter $x$. Btw, you are not calculating $P(Y=0)$ but $P(Y=0\mid X=x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that you wrote is correct. You know that 
$$
(Y|X=x)\sim Poiss(x),
$$
so 
$$
P(Y=k|X=x)=\frac{e^{-x}\cdot x^{k}}{k!},\quad k\ge0.
$$
Plugging this (computed for $k=0$) into your formula, we get
$$
P(Y=0)
=\sum_{x\ge1}p(1-p)^{x-1}e^{-x}
=\frac pe\cdot\frac1{1-e^{-1}(1-p)}.
$$

Comment: i don't get why this: "so 
$$
P(Y=k|X=x)=\frac{e^{-x}\cdot x^{k}}{k!},\quad k\ge0.
$$"

Comment: This is precisely the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Discrete_distributions) of $(Y\mid X=x)\sim Poiss(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have most of what you need.

$P(Y=0|X=x)=e^{-x}$ (Because in this case $Y$ is Poisson with parameter $x$).

So

$$\begin{array}{ccl}P(Y=0)&=&e^{-1}P(X=1)+e^{-2}P(X=2)+e^{-3}P(X=3)+\cdots\\&=&e^{-1}\cdot p+e^{-2}p(1-p)+e^{-3}p(1-p)^2+\cdots\end{array}$$

This last is recognizably a geometric series.